# How to test JWT expiration in Spring REST?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, testing

I want to write a unit test for checking expiration of JWT. I used Mockito.spy to throw an exception, but not works. So far, here is my progress:

```
@Test
public void hello_fail_expired_token() throws Exception {
    User user = FakeDataGenerator.generateFakeUser();
    User registeredUser = userService.register(user.getEmail(), user.getPassword(), user.getName());
    String token = jwtService.generateToken(registeredUser);
    Mockito.doThrow(new JWTExpiredException()).when(Mockito.spy(jwtService)).verifyToken(token);
    MockHttpServletRequestBuilder mockRequest = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/user/hello")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
    System.out.println(mockMvc.perform(mockRequest).andReturn().getResponse().getContentAsString());
}
```

After the execution of this method, no exception is throwed. What is my fault?

Comment: The issue probably lies in how you've configured mockMvc.  It's likely not invoking your verifyToken method.  Place a breakpoint in your jwtService.verifyToken method to see that it's being called.  If it is, ensure that your matchers are correct.  If it's not being called, make sure that you've configured mockMvc with the FilterChainProxy.  If you'll post more details on how mockMvc is built and how jwtService is injected it will help in answering it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out. Before:

```
@Autowired
JWTService jwtService;
```

Now:

```
@Spy
JWTService jwtService;
```

And in test method, before:

```
Mockito.doThrow(new JWTExpiredException()).when(Mockito.spy(jwtService)).verifyToken(token);
```

After:

```
Mockito.doThrow(new JWTExpiredException()).when(jwtService).verifyToken(token);
```